# Where are downloaded updates for macOS Monterey saved?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, apple-id, mac-appstore, monterey

I found that manual updates for Safari and Xcode are stored in `/Library/Updates`, but I can't find manual updates for macOS, I have macOS 12.5.1 installed, where is the 1.59 GB macOS 12.6 installation file stored?

[image]

Comment: once fully downloaded it is put in /Applications

Comment: I will clarify I have 12.5.1 installed where the file is stored installation 12.6 with a volume of 1.59 GB

Comment: It's likely to be in a hidden temp folder, e.g. in /var or /tmp. Updates don't get saved to /Applications; only complete installers.